# Android - Add TextView to custom activity to display in multiple activities

Tags: android

I tried add TextView to custom activity to display in multiple activities, but nothing is shown.
This is my custom activity code :

```
LinearLayout layout;

public void SetupFooter() {
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM|android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); 

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("abc");
    layout.addView(tv);
}
```

This is my main_activity xml code that I want to add the footer to :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnGoToTop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/buttongototop"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I call SetupFooter() in extended activities, nothing is shown.
Are there any problems with my code ?
Sorry for my bad English and thanks for helping me!

Edited :
I added this : addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
It's shown now but it's not placed at the bottom, how could I make it stay at the bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating 2 views in your function, a text view and a linear layout.  You're adding the text view to the linear layout, but you aren't putting the linear layout anywhere, so it isn't appearing.  If you want to add it to the linear layout already in your xml, you need to give it an id so you can get a reference to it with findViewById, then add the text view to that.

Comment: Hi, I added this addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); It's shown now but it's not in the bottom, it's in the top..